# Socat corrupt image file

Tags: linux, bash, apache, socat

I use 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork  EXEC:./bashttpd' for http server. when try to receive image file from client socat remove some byte and corrupt my image.

```
correct:
01b0   0a 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44   ..PNG........IHD
01c0   52 00 00 07 80 00 00 04 38 08 02 00 00 00 67 b1   R.......8.....g.
01d0   56 14 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 11 b0 00 00   V.

incorrect:(socat -> read line -> xxh)
00000000: 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a                                .PNG..
00000000: 1a 0a                                            ..
00000000: 0d 49 48 44 52 07 80 04 38 08 02 67 b1 56 14 09  .IHDR...8..g.V
```

how to solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: The first byte seems to be removed. It is 0xa, a LF if my memory doesn't fail. Don't you have any line ending translation running, right? Check for transfer modes to be binary, not text.

Comment: how to change transfer mode in socat after detect data stream OR how to run in binary mod?  (socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork,binary -> not run)

Comment: i use  "cat >| output_file" vs "read line" after detect data stream and now image is correct. :)